# Incompatible types in my code?

Tags: android

I don't understand why line ''while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){' is showing a red line and saying incompatible types? Could someone please explain to me why this is so?

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
    BufferedReader reader;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        //stores stream object
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        //will help user read data line by line
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())) ! = null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Comment: while ((line == reader.readLine()) !== null ) {
//your further code here
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
while ((line = reader.readLine())) ! = null) { ...
```

to

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { ...
```

**EDIT:**

Delete one closing parentheses.